# Prime ratio limit

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm curious about approximating numbers as the ratio of primes.

let $p_n$ be the nth prime
let $g_r(p)$ be the smallest prime greater than $r \times p$

looks like $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} g_r(p_n)/p_n = r$

Is this true? How to prove it?

Comment: Are you able to prove the case when $r=1$?

Comment: @Crostul: I think the prime number theorem yields a relatively easy proof for $r = 1$.